# VB 0B temp file created in Outlook temp folder when adding Outlook attachment for second time

Tags: vb.net, outlook

This behavior is odd and difficult to describe so I will give it my best shot.

1. With Outlook closed, file attaches normally time after time.
2. With Outlook open, file attaches normally for the first time and then creates a 0B temp file each time after.
3. Deleting Content.Outlook has no effect.
4. No matter what the pdf file that I'm trying to attach is always created successfully. It seems to be failing when being copied over to the temp directory to be attached.

So for some reason, having Outlook open is preventing me from running the following code multiple times successfully.

Here's the code that creates the attachment and adds the attachment to an email.

```
    Me.PrintForm1.PrintFileName = Jobpath & "\DrawingChecklist.pdf"
    PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)

    'Log
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\" & "Log.txt", "User: " & Environment.UserName & " Saved: " & txtQuoteNumber.Text & " at: " & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & Environment.NewLine, True) 'True appends, False overwites

    Dim OutlookMessage As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim AppOutlook As New Outlook.Application


    Try

        'Make sure file has been created
        Dim xx = 0
        Do While Dir(Jobpath & "\DrawingChecklist.pdf") = "" And xx < 10
            'MsgBox("File doens't exist." & " " & Jobpath & "\DrawingChecklist.pdf")
            xx = xx + 1
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Loop

        'Double check file has been created
        If Dir(Jobpath & "\DrawingChecklist.pdf") = "" Then
            MsgBox("File doens't exist." & " " & Jobpath & "\DrawingChecklist.pdf")
        End If

        OutlookMessage = AppOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem)
        Dim Recipents As Outlook.Recipients = OutlookMessage.Recipients
        Recipents.Add(File.ReadAllText(ExePath & "DraftingEmail.txt"))
        Recipents.ResolveAll()
        OutlookMessage.Subject = txtCompany.Text & " " & txtQuoteNumber.Text & " " & txtJobName.Text
        OutlookMessage.Attachments.Add(Jobpath & "\DrawingChecklist.pdf")

        OutlookMessage.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML
        OutlookMessage.Display()
        'OutlookMessage.Send()
        'MsgBox("Mail sent!")



        'Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show("Mail could Not be sent") 'if you dont want this message, simply delete this line 
    Finally
        OutlookMessage = Nothing
        AppOutlook = Nothing
    End Try
```

Comment: What does `Jobpath` stand for?

Comment: It's just the path to where the attachment is stored.

Comment: Where? How does it look like?

Comment: An example of what it would look like is "\\acs03\gmapp\Quotes\TESTZACH\test\zt20-02_test".

Comment: Do you get any issues with local files?

Comment: I'm not sure since non of the files ever attached would be local.

Answer (score 0):

The [Attachments.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Outlook.Attachments.Add) method creates a new attachment in the `Attachments` collection. The source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

The file should be located on the local disk - you need to download it first on the local drive.

Comment: Is it possible to attach the file without it being copied locally first?

Comment: Office applications are designed to deal with local files only. So, it is recommended to deal with local files. Moreover, the remote location can be offline or just have network latency problems.

Comment: So my best bet would be copying the file locally, attaching it, and then removing the local file?

Comment: The file copies over as 0 KB size which doesn't make any sense. It's almost like something has the file open or something along those lines, but I can't find anything that would have it open unless the application itself has it locked since it created it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by adding a short delay before adding the attachment.

```
Threading.Thread.Sleep(300)
```